# CSS How to make the <span> same height as <input>?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I just simply want to make the Search button occupy full height as that of `input`. You can see the background color is applying only over the area of text. Is there any other way rather than applying padding to btn so it will automatically scale up if `input` padding is changed?

```css
.GroupSearch {
  text-align: center;
}

.GroupSearch__input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.GroupSearch__search-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(0, 92, 128);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div className="GroupSearch">
  <input className="GroupSearch__input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Group Name" />
  <span className="GroupSearch__search-btn">Search</span>
</div>
```

Comment: className is not a valid attribute, I think you mean class.

Comment: @Esko i think it's JSX not HTML :)

Comment: @MihaiT Might be but there is not mention about it.

Comment: have you tried input-group-addon class to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox will do that by default.

```css
.GroupSearch {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.GroupSearch__input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.GroupSearch__search-btn {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="GroupSearch">
  <input class="GroupSearch__input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Group Name" />
  <span class="GroupSearch__search-btn">Search</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

THe most simple way to do it is to give same padding to the span as to the input. ( considering that both input and span have the same font-size and line-height ). Also input has a default `border-width:2px` so the padding will become `padding:12px 10px`.

Other solutions would include flexbox. But here's the quick fix :

```css
.GroupSearch {
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.GroupSearch__input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.GroupSearch__search-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(0, 92, 128);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="GroupSearch">
  <input class="GroupSearch__input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Group Name" />
  <span class="GroupSearch__search-btn">Search</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not there other way so it will automatically expand if input padding is changed

Comment: @UnityHour added the answer above which makes it automatically expand if padding of input is changed. : [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008772/2450196)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have just put `display: table` on outer container and `display: table-cell` on inner items (input and span).
[Read more](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table) on `display: table`

Additionally you may add some left and right padding to the button, to make it look a bit spacious.

```css
.GroupSearch {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.GroupSearch__input {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.GroupSearch__search-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(0, 92, 128);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="GroupSearch">
  <input class="GroupSearch__input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Group Name" />
  <span class="GroupSearch__search-btn">Search</span>
</div>
```